# File is readable for php code run from php-cli directly and not readable for php code run through php-cli inside bash script

Tags: php, linux, bash

I am calling a php script from a bash file by root user. The php code gives an error of file not readable exception. If I run the same php sript from php-cli by root user, the file is readable.

I have own the file using command

```
chown root:www-data "file"
```

and make the file readable by

```
chmod +r "file"
```

Here's the content of my bash script

```
while true; do
  echo "Waiting for file changes"
  OUTPUT=`inotifywait -rq -e create --format='%w%f' '/var/www/storage/app/public/raw_image'`
  chown root:www-data "$OUTPUT"
  sleep 0.5
  php /var/www/scripts/script.php "$OUTPUT"
  echo "Files were changed"
done
```

The file permission for my bash script file is `0755`

Comment: Share your bash script to understand more

Comment: put the code in your question, not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Not sure might be a shebang issue. Try below solution one by one most probably first one solve your problem

- chmod +rx "script.php"
- `#!/usr/bin/php /var/www/scripts/script.php "$OUTPUT"`